# Python's asyncio.Event() across different classes

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-class, python-can

I'm writing a Python program to interact with a device based on a CAN Bus. I'm using the python-can module successfully for this purpose. I'm also using asyncio to react to asynchronous events. I have written a "CanBusManager" class that is used by the "CanBusSequencer" class. The "CanBusManager" class takes care of generating/sending/receiving messages, and the CanBusSequencer drives the sequence of messages to be sent.
At some point in the sequence I want to wait until a specific message is received to "unlock" the remaining messages to be sent in the sequence. Overview in code:

main.py

```
async def main():
   
   event = asyncio.Event()
   sequencer = CanBusSequencer(event)
   task = asyncio.create_task(sequencer.doSequence())
   await task
 
asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

canBusSequencer.py

```
from canBusManager import CanBusManager

class CanBusSequencer:
 
   def __init__(self, event)
 
      self.event = event
      self.canManager = CanBusManager(event)

   async def doSequence(self):
 
      for index, row in self.df_sequence.iterrows():
         if:...
            self.canManager.sendMsg(...)
         else:
            self.canManager.sendMsg(...)
            await self.event.wait()
            self.event.clear()
```

canBusManager.py

```
import can

class CanBusManager():
 
   def __init__(self, event):
 
      self.event = event
      self.startListening()
 
 **EDIT**
    def startListening(self):
    
       self.msgNotifier = can.Notifier(self.canBus, self.receivedMsgCallback)
 **EDIT**
 
   def receivedMsgCallback(self, msg):
 
      if(msg == ...):
         self.event.set()
```

For now my program stays by the await self.event.wait(), even though the relevant message is received and the self.event.set() is executed. Running the program with debug = True reveals an

```
RuntimeError: Non-thread-safe operation invoked on an event loop other than the current one
```

that I don't really get. It has to do with the asyncio event loop, somehow not properly defined/managed. I'm coming from the C++ world and I'm currently writing my first large program with Python. Any guidance would be really appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't explain how you arrange for `receivedMsgCallback` to be invoked.

If it is invoked by a classic "async" API which uses threads behind the scenes, then it will be invoked from outside the thread that runs the event loop. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html), asyncio primitives are **not thread-safe**, so invoking `event.set()` from another thread doesn't properly synchronize with the running event loop, which is why your program doesn't wake up when it should.

If you want to do anything asyncio-related, such as invoke `Event.set`, from outside the event loop thread, you need to use [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading) or equivalent. For example:

```
    def receivedMsgCallback(self, msg):
        if msg == ...:
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.event.set)
```

The event loop object should be made available to the `CanBusManager` object, perhaps by passing it to its constructor and assigning it to `self.loop`.

On a side note, if you are creating a task only to await it immediately, you don't need a task in the first place. In other words, you can replace `task = asyncio.create_task(sequencer.doSequence()); await task` with the simpler `await sequencer.doSequence()`.

Comment: Awesome, it works. The receivedMsgCallback() is defined by the through the python-can module. I now pass the event loop to the constructor. Thanks for the explanation!